# How to specify the labels for circles and lines with the tikz package?

Tags: tikz-pgf, graphs

I need to draw the graph (left in Figure).

[image]

I start to use the tikz package and my atempt is in right figure.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage[english,russian]{babel}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
\begin{center}
\begin{tikzpicture}[
node distance = 50pt,
     C/.style = {circle, draw, minimum size=20pt,
                 node contents={}}
                    ]
\node (v1) [C];
%
\node (v8) [C, below of=v1];
\node (v9) [C, right of=v8];
%
\node (v7) [C, below of=v8];
%
\node (v6) [C, below of=v7];
\node (v5) [C, left  of=v6];
\node (v2) [C, right of=v6];
%
\node (v3) [C, below of=v6];
\node (v4) [C, left of =v3];
%%
\draw   (v1) -- (v9)
        (v9) -- (v5)
        (v1) -- (v2)
        (v9) -- (v8)
        (v8) -- (v7)
        (v7) -- (v6)
        (v2) -- (v6)
        (v6) -- (v5)
        (v2) -- (v3)
        (v5) -- (v3)
        (v5) -- (v4)
        (v3) -- (v4);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{center}
\end{document}
```

**My major question:** how to specify the labels for circles and lines?

Answer (score 1):

```
\documentclass[tikz, border=1cm]{standalone}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[
node distance = 50pt,
C/.style={circle, draw, minimum size=20pt}
]
\node[C] (v1) {V1};
\node[C, below of=v1] (v8) {V8};
\node[C, right of=v8] (v9) {V9};
\node[C, below of=v8] (v7) {V7};
\node[C, below of=v7] (v6) {V6};
\node[C, left  of=v6] (v5) {V5};
\node[C, right of=v6] (v2) {V2};
\node[C, below of=v6] (v3) {V3};
\node[C, left of =v3] (v4) {V4};
\draw
(v1) --node{1} (v9)
(v9) --node[pos=0.8]{2} (v5)
(v1) --node[pos=0.8]{0.5} (v2)
(v9) --node{10} (v8)
(v8) --node{8} (v7)
(v7) --node{9} (v6)
(v2) --node{1} (v6)
(v6) --node{1} (v5)
(v2) --node{1} (v3)
(v5) --node{1} (v3)
(v5) --node{1} (v4)
(v3) --node{1} (v4);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: Connected graph]

Comment: I have solved the original question with your answer. But I have the problem with position setup for v7 and v4. Is it possible to change the title or should I start a new topic?

Comment: You should not change title or intent of a question. If it is a small thing not worth starting a question, try asking me in a comment, or try the chat room.

Comment: Thank you, how to move the node v7 to left?

Comment: You can use e.g `\node[C, below of=v8, xshift=-1cm] (v7) {V7};`. Note that because other nodes are placed relative to `(v7)`, you are not only moving that node.